# Remove specific element from an array

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

I have different forms in my website and I would like to save the data in different Database tables. My form send all the values to be inserted into the database using ajax.

```
var myData = {event_type: 'bike', user_id: mUserId, country: mCountry, city: mCity, state: mState, addressMap: mAddressMap, location: mLocation, zip: mZip,lat : latPos, lng: lngPos , distance : mDistance, unitDistance: mUnitDistance, rideType : mType, pace: mPace, event_type: eventType  }; //post variables
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/processNewRide.php",
      data: myData,
      success:function(data){
        replaceWin.html(data); //replace info window with new html
        Marker.setDraggable(false); //set marker to fixed
        Marker.setIcon('pin_blue.png'); //replace icon
        $('.addEventPop').fadeOut('slow');
                 $('#mask').fadeOut('slow');
                         infowindow.open(map,Marker); // show the marker                 
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError); //throw any errors
            }
    });
```

since `processNewRide.php` has to deal with an unknown number of values and different column names, I managed to insert them into the database using:

```
    $key_value_array = $_POST;
$eventType = filter_var($_POST["event_type"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


    $table = $eventType;
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' '; 
    $columns = '(';
    $values = '(';
    foreach ($key_value_array as $k => $v) {
        $columns .= '`' . $k . '`, ';
        $values .= "'" . $v . "', ";
    }
    $columns = rtrim($columns, ', ') . ')';
    $values = rtrim($values, ', ') . ')';
    $sql .= $columns . ' VALUES ' . $values;

    $q = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute();
```

this works only if I passed the exact number of values and the key in the array is equal to my columns name. The problem is that I would like to add some values (i.e `country, city, state, city, addressMap, location, zip, lat, lng`) in a generic table call `Event` (common to all the different forms) and some more specific into the other table (i.e. `distance, rideType, ridePace`). Since I know which parameters I want to insert into Event, is it possible to remove those values from the array `$key_value_array` ?

UPDATE:

As suggested I had to use `unset()` so I solved doing this:

```
unset($key_value_array['city']);
unset($key_value_array['state']);
unset($key_value_array['country']);
unset($key_value_array['location']);
unset($key_value_array['zip']);
unset($key_value_array['lat']);
unset($key_value_array['lng']);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "(common to all the different forms)"? If you're wanting to remove values from an array you could `unset()` or `array_pop()`, whichever is more appropriate.

Comment: I mean that all the Basic info (country, city, state, city, addressMap, location, zip, lat, png) are stored in Event and all the forms have these fields. Some other specific info are stored in other tables like Bike or Run.

Comment: Okay, I am still unclear on what it is exactly that you're trying to accomplish

Comment: `array_pop`— Pop the element off the end of array. I would like to remove from `$key_value_array` some specific element (country, city, state, city, addressMap, location, zip, lat, png) before the loop.

Comment: Ok, I think I realized what I need to do no. probably `array_search` and then `unset` the element